# Cakephp losing all CSS style when user get back to previous page visited in browser

Tags: php, css, cakephp

I'm facing an issue when my webpage loses all of CSS styles in CakePHP.

This happen when the user tries to go back to the previous page when click on back arrow in browser.

Its seems CakePHP cannot reload all the CSS and JS Styles.

When user access any page through links inside web, all styles setted in default.ctp works fine.

See my default.ctp:

```
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');
    echo $this->Html->css('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous');
    echo $this->Html->css('jquery.fancybox');
    echo $this->Html->css('fullcalendar');
    echo $this->Html->css('xcharts.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('select2');
    echo $this->Html->css('style');
    echo $this->Html->css('jquery.dataTables');

    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('css');

    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-2.1.0.min.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('ChartNew.js');        
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui.min.js');       
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.justifiedgallery.min.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('tinymce.min.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.tinymce.min.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('devoops.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.dataTables.js');


    echo $this->fetch('script');
```

But I guess this is not the real problem since it works fine if the page is accessed through links without going back through  the history stored to the browser.

Is there anything I have to do so CakePHP needs to reload all styles again?
I have this concern because my webpage will be accessed by paid customers and I need to fix this issue.

If I have to inform any further information, please tell me.
This issue happens in all of pages with no exception.

**UPDATING INFORMATION**

I thought it could be any problem inside .htaccess that CSS and JS files not reloading.
Just adding information how these three .htaccess files are setted:

Root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Inside app/ directory:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Inside app/webroot directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Disable Back button Or Check if the user clicks back button then refresh the page so that page will refreshed and styles will load properly

Comment: I thinks this is not a good solution for my website since this could be awful for user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found symptom of this problem. For some reason, CakePHP cannot cache the layout everytime I try to go back to a visited previously page. To solve my problem, I included this line:

```
$this->disableCache();
```

This line was included inside `beforeFilter()` function in `AppController`. Now everything works properly and CSS & JS files seems load again.

This is a closest solution I found. More than 5 days shooting in the dark to find this.